# tcl check key value format

Tags: regex, tcl

I would like to check if the line is in key-value format, so I do:

```
        set index [string first "=" $line]

        if { $index == -1 } {
            #error
        }

        set text  [string range $line [expr $index + 1] end]

        if { [string first "=" $text ] != -1 } {
            #error
        }
```

How can I write this check as a regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing for the last `if` statement.

Through regex, you can use:

```
% regexp {=(.*)$} $line - text
1 # If there's no "=", it will be zero and nothing will be stored in $text, 
  # as $text will not exist
```

In an `if` block, you can use:

```
if {[regexp {=(.*)$} $line - text]} {
    puts $text
} else {
    # error
}
```

**EDIT:** To check if the string contains only one `=` sign:

```
if {[regexp {^[^=]*=[^=]*$} $line]} {
    return 1
} else {
    return 0
}
```

`^` means the beginning of a string.
`[^=]` means any character except the equal sign.
`[^=]*` means any character except the equal sign occurring 0 or more times.
`=` matches only one equal sign.
`$` matches the end of the string.

So, it checks whether the string has only one equal sign.

`1` means that the line contains only 1 equal sign, `0` means there are no equal sign, or more than 1 equal sign.

Comment: [Jerry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1578604/jerry) How can I check if the line is contain exactly one equal sign?

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan I edited my answer to check for the occurrence of only one equal sign.

Answer (score 4):

You could also split the string using `=` as a separator and check the number of resulting fields

```
set fields [split $line =]
switch [llength $fields] {
    1 {error "no = sign"}
    2 {lassign $fields key value}
    default {error "too many = signs"}
}
```

Comment: This feels like a much better way of parsing a key-value item. The key and value are immediately available. Sure, the OP can modify the regexp and the code quite easily to extract the key and value at the same time as checking the syntax, but this feels a much more native Tcl solution.